# Algorithm/pseudocode for UK Taxation (capital gains)

Tags: python, algorithm, pseudocode

I've been looking to implement the algorithm (or pseudocode) for the UK CGT taxation (as described on [HRMC's website](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/shares-and-capital-gains-tax-hs284-self-assessment-helpsheet/hs-shares-and-capital-gains-tax-2015)) but I can't get my head around the sort of algorithm I'd need to do this efficiently without looping too many times. I've tried to search as much as possible, and even tried a few of my own implementations but can't seem to get it to work properly.

There's a proper example on [TimeToTrade's website](https://wiki.timetotrade.com/Share_Identification_Rules) as well. I've tried explain here to the best of my ability.

Assuming I have the following table of buy/sells (date in yyyy-mm-dd):

```
id action amount per share  total        date
1.  buy    2000      £1     £2000  2017-05-05 10:00
2.  buy    1000      £1     £1000  2017-05-10 10:00
3.  buy    1000    £1.5     £1500  2017-06-01 10:00
4.  sell   2000    £2.5     £5000  2017-06-01 10:00
5.  sell   1000      £2     £2000  2017-06-01 10:00
6.  buy    1500    £0.5      £750  2017-06-20 10:00
```

**According to HRMC the following rules have to be respected:**

- A sale is first matched to a buy (FIFO) on the same day
- A sale is then matched to a buy (FIFO) within the next 30 days
- A sale is finally matched with the averaged buys in the past (pooled into a "Section 104 holding")

**This gives me the following calculation when doing it by hand:**

1. **1+2** pooled = Total 3000 shares @ £3000 (£1 per share)
2. **3** has sell transaction(s) on the same day, so this is not pooled for now.

   - 1000 of the 2000 shares are matched with the buy on the same day (first in first out)

     - 1000 shares @ £1.5 = £1500 - a gain of 1000*£2.5-£1500 = £1000
   - 1000 of the remaining 1000 shares from sell **4** are matched with the buy in the next 30 days (**6**)

     - 1000 shares @ £0.5 = £500 - a gain of 1000*£2.5-£500 = £2000
   - Sell transaction 4 has a total chargeable gain of £1000+£2000=£3000
3. **5** can no longer match with buy **3** on the same day, as it has been depleted of shares to match

   - 500 of the 1000 shares are matched with the buy **6** as it has 500 shares remaining

     - 500 shares @ 0.5 = £250 - a gain of (500*£2)-£250 = £750
   - 500 of the remaining 500 shares are finally matched with the pooled holdings from **(1+2)**

     - 500 shares @ 1 = £500 - a gain of (500*£2)-£500 = £500
   - Sell transaction 5 has a total chargeable gain of £750+500=£1250

Total chargeable gain **£3000+£1250=£4250** - Amount left to carry 2500 shares@£2500

**Pseudocode of what I think is required**:

```
- loop through all trades chronologically  
  - if it's a sell trade  
    - check if there any trades on the same day to match  
    - check for future buy trades (where sell trade < buy trade < sell trade + 30 days)  
    - use existing holdings if there are none and/or the matches aren't sufficient to fill the sell  
  - if it's a buy trade  
    - add it to a 'same_day' array  
    - loop through 'same_day' array on the next day to sum it up into a 'section 104 holding'  
- keep reference of each trade in an indexed by trade id dictionary/object/hashmap to subtract and such when matching sell trades
```

Any pointer in the right direction would be much appreciated.